# Paypal and Wix integration

Tags: paypal, store, shopping-cart

I have a wix website with the wix online store.  I'm using paypal as the merchant to accept payments for my products.  However, buyers have no option to pay directly with their credit card (i.e. without creating a paypal) when they click on Checkout.  The info available online indicates that this is possible (payment as a guest).  Apparently, if I have a Business account (which I do) I can disable/enable the feature in my selling tools in the Profile. and check the yes/no box under PayPal Account.  I don't see these options when I browse my account, although I am able to accept payments now.

I've tried changing my shopping cart from the default wix shopping cart to a Paypal shopping cart but I am unable to figure this out either. It does not appear that wix allows this.  Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With PayPal Payments Standard, which is what Wix appears to be using, the guest checkout option is entirely dependent on local browser cookies.  If any user in the local browser has ever signed in to a PayPal account then the system will assume that's what they're going to do during PayPal checkouts and it won't make the guest checkout option very prominent (although, it is still there.  Usually as a small link.)

[PayPal Express Checkout APIs](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) allow you to force the guest checkout option using specific request parameters, however, that's a completely different integration than what Wix is using from what I can see.  It's not something you'll be able to do in a hosted (and often very limited, as you're discovering) solution like Wix.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate PayPal using their REST API & Wix's development platform Corvid. See a tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nB8cvfviIJc

In the video you will notice that the parameter "payee_preferred": "IMMEDIATE_PAYMENT_REQUIRED" is passed which will force the express checkout window.